# link to answer in exercise in arabic

Tags: xetex, hyperref, labels, arabic, exercises

I tried to create this in Arabic but I failed
how can I get model like this in Arabic

[image]

when I click in correction( in arabic الحل ) I go to the answer of exercise I click to the execise (in arabic التمرين) return to exercise
Knowing that I want to write all of the article in Arabic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Can you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?